# why the hyperlink cannot jump to the right place

Tags: hyperref

Today ,I use the package `hyperref` to create hyperlink .However ,some links can jump to the right place while some hyperlinks cannot jump to the destination .

my mini code

```
  \documentclass[UTF8]{ctexrt}
  \usepackage {hyperref}
  \usepackage {graphicx}
  \begin{document}
  \section{welcome}
  Hi,welcome to latex  \hyperref[fig1 ]{fig1 }
  Hi,welcome to latex
   \hyperref[fig2 ]{fig2}
  Hi,welcome to latex
 \includegraphics{fig2.eps}
 \label{fig2}

  \includegraphics{fig3.eps}
 \label{fig3}
  Hi,we
  \includegraphics{fig1.eps}
 \label{fig1}
  come to latex
  Hi,welcome to latex
  Hi,welcome to latex
  Hi,welcome to latex

  \end{document }
```

so I wonder how to.solve .

Comment: You need a "counter stepping mechanism" in order to fix a position where the hyperlink will go. If this is not used, then you need to place a manual `\phantomsection` to mark the hyper target. So, place a `\phantomsection` before each `\label` where you want *that* `\hyperref` to jump to.

Comment: @Werner,which package contains the command `\plantomsection `

Comment: [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) provides `\phantomsection`. See the [`hyperref` documentation](http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html) and search for `\phantomsection`. It'll give some information on where it's used/how to use it.

Comment: @Werner,dear friend,thanks sincerely,It goes well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\label` is used for cross-referencing in LaTeX, which also generates a hyperlink to the corresponding unit, in this case the section (if you use `\label` inside an equation it would be the equation, etcetera).  What you appear to need is `\hypertarget`+`\hyperlink`.

Edit in response to the comment:

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}

\usepackage {hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{welcome}

\lipsum[1] 

\hyperlink{fig1}{fig1 }

\lipsum[2]

\hyperlink{fig2}{fig2}

\lipsum[3]

\hypertarget{fig2}{figure 2}

\lipsum[5]

\hypertarget{fig3}{figure 3!}

\lipsum[6]

\hypertarget{fig1}{figure 1!}

\lipsum[7]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Providing an MWE that demonstrates your solution would be helpful.

Comment: sorry ,your method makes the chinese characters become the garbage english word.

Comment: Just change the article class back to what you had before.