# Question on why hyperlinks are not aligned with adjusted page counting

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

When I adjust the page countering the hyperreference under the `hyperref` package shows the correct page, but when the hyperlink is clicked it takes me to the page which had been indicated without the adjustment of the page counting.

Can this be rectified?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}    
\setcounter{page}{-1}    
\newpage

empty 

\newpage

test\label{test}

\newpage

test at page \pageref{test}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154218/why-the-hyperlink-cannot-jump-to-the-right-place?rq=1 help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the point where your `\label` is, no counter has been incremented, so the hyperlink points to the beginning of the document.

In fact, if you take a look at your `.aux` file, you will see a line

```
\newlabel{test}{{}{0}{}{Doc-Start}{}}
```

One way to circumvent this is to add a `\phantomsection` before your label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{-1}
\newpage

empty

\newpage

test\phantomsection\label{test}

\newpage

test at page \pageref{test}
\end{document}
```

The corresponding line in the `.aux` file is now

```
\newlabel{test}{{}{0}{}{section*.1}{}}
```

and the hyperlink points to the right place.